# iPhone 3.0 SDK freely availible?

Tags: iphone, dashcode

In the United States, is the iPhone 3.0 SDK freely available like how the iPhone 2.x SDK was? I have an application that I wrote in Dashcode and I would like to update it to see if it solves any of the bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** When reading this answer please bear in mind that I have no awareness of 'Dashcode'

You need to have an account with the [iPhone dev center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/) but you do not need to be enrolled in a paid [iPhone developer program](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/).

Answer (score 0):

Dashcode 3.0 is included with [Snow Leopard](http://www.apple.com/macosx/specs.html) (Mac OS X 10.6).  On the DVD, there is a folder called ***Optional Installs*** which includes **Xcode** 3.2 (which includes **Dashcode** 3.0 as part of the **Essentials** item).

If you wrote the application with Dashcode, then it was a "Mobile Safari app".  I don't think you'd need *any* iPhone SDK to work with that kind of an application -- since developers were developing iPhone "web apps" for a year before the SDK existed.  In that case, a new iPhone SDK won't affect your application.

The new Dashcode might help though, as well as samples that highlight new cooperation between browsers and iPhone/iPod Touch hardware.  For instance, check out the [Safari/iPhoneOrientation](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/samplecode/iPhoneOrientation/index.html) sample (no login required).